# Usage of did while describing the subject

Tags: past-tense

If you're using **did** followed by a description of the subject, will the verb that follows be in present or past?

For example, should it be

> **Did** the person you **choose** have the key?

or

> **Did** the person you **chose** have the key?

---

Second example

> **Did** the book you **pick** make sense?

vs

> **Did** the book you **picked** make sense?

---

Third example

> **Did** the school he **goes** to

vs

> **Did** the school he **went** to

Answer (score 2):

For most contexts, the verb form in the construction ***Did*** [object] [**that**] [subject] [verb] [blah blah]? should be Past Tense (matching initial ***did***), not Present Tense. But this isn't really a "grammatical rule" - the verb tense depends on *what you mean* in any given context.

---

The first two of OP's example verbs *(choose, pick)* aren't very helpful, because they have the same meaning, and in both cases it's quite possible the addressee (the person being asked the question) is ***currently*** selecting a person / book, so Present Tense ***choose / pick*** is a "valid" choice.

On the other hand, the fact that we're asking for more details about the selected person / book implies that the addressee ***must already know*** who / what he is selecting (i.e. - he's *already* chosen), so Past Tense is *also* potentially "valid".

---

With the third pair, things are more clear-cut. The speaker is asking a question about a particular school - specifically, the school someone *else* ("he") ***either*** currently attends, or did attend in the past.

The speaker would usually already know whether the person *still* went to the school being asked about, and that would dictate whether to use Present / Past *(go / went)*. In the unlikely event the speaker *didn't* know, he'd have to say something "awkward" like...

> 3: *Did the school he **goes to or went to** have a swimming pool?*

...OR get round the problem by rephrasing to, for example,...

> 4: *Did **his school** have a swimming pool?*

Note that in *both* the above, the implication is *the relevant school **probably** doesn't still have a swimming pool* (if the speaker thought it still ***did***, he'd have asked ***Does*** [that school] have a pool?

---

As an example question using a verb where it's almost impossible to contrive a meaningful context for a Present Tense verb, consider...

> 5: *Did the woman you marry have children?*
>    OR (using Present Continuous)...
>    6: *Did the woman you **are marrying** have children?*

Technically speaking, both the above are "syntactically valid". But the woman being asked about is obviously alive *now* (she must be, since the addressee is marrying her), so if she ***did*** have children at some point in the past, she must ***still*** have children - unless they all died before their mother (an unlikely scenario, but even then we could truthfully say she ***did*** have children; she just hasn't *"**got**"* them any more).

---

TL;DR: In most contexts, the natural tense choice is Past throughout: ***Did*** [object] [that] [subject] [**verbed**] [blah blah]? (note that the word ***that*** is optional in such constructions). But there are contexts where Present ***Did*** [object] [that] [subject] [**verbs**] [blah blah]? correctly identifies the relevant "object" being asked about.

Comment: There is no reason to limit this to just the past and present: ***Did*** *the woman you **will marry next year** have children (before now)?* The verb tenses are completely disconnected from each other, syntactically speaking. In fact, it's *did [the X you Y] Z?*, where *[the X you Y]* is a noun phrase with an embedded verb.

Comment: @JasonBassford: Yeah, it's syntactically valid, but I think your Past+Future example requires much the same contrived context as my examples #5, #6 (and I can't help noticing how much difference adding ***before now*** makes). Plus my #5 *could* be interpreted as equivalent to *Did the woman you **are to marry** have children?*, in which case it would effectively be Future anyway.